# How to get nodejs callback result

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm having hard time trying to get the callback result and pass it to the page and so far I have setup correctly the connection and I'm getting the data if I do console.log.

My question: How do I get callback result data and pass it to endpoint (anypage)

Here's my query.js code

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'postgres',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
})

const getUsers = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
  }

module.exports = { getUsers }
```

My app.js:

```
app.get('/users', db.getUsers, function(err, result) {
   //Display result or pass it to a different page where it can show on the page..

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.get('/users', db.getUsers)` only will do what you are looking for. You don't have to pass second callback function. You already passing `db.getUsers` as a callback and passing request, response object, calling `response.status(200).json()` will end request-reponse cycle.

**Update Based on user's requirement**

**change db.getUsers as below** :

```
const getUsers = (callback) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        callack(error,null);
      }
       callback(null,results.rows);
    })
  }
```

**Calling getUsers**

```
app.get('/users',function(req,res) {

              db.getUsers(function(err,rows){
                 if (err) {
                   console.log(err)
                   res.status(500).json({"msg":"internal server error"})
                  }
                  res.status(200).json(rows)

               })

            });
```

Comment: I guess I'm wondering once you get the response how would you display on the UI that record

Comment: @NickKahn do you understand what `response.status(200).json(results.rows)` does?

Comment: I see what you mean by `will end request-response cycle` so can I just return the data from `db.getUsers` and get the `request response` on the `app.js` ?

Comment: @NickKahn I have updated answer based on your  comment

Answer (score 0):

As I see you want to leverage the middleware of the `express` framework. Something you can do is that you can save it in the express `request` object.

```
const getUsers = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM Employee ORDER BY id ASC', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        else {
            request.employees = results;
            next();
        }
    })
}

app.get('/users', db.getUsers, function(request, response) {
   response.status(200).json(request.employees.rows)
});
```

**But I don't think you should do this way**

The correct way would be to do the way as in sandeep's answer. You should return the results from your getUsers function and just use it in your endpoint.